# NodeJS Schema virtual function if clause malfunctioning

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am getting a false truth from this script, and it's baffling. Using virtuals in nodejs. 'XFactor' is essentially a scale from 0.0 to 1.0 which represents the relationship between variable 1 and variable 2.

```
Schema.virtual('XFactor').get(function() {
  if (this.variable1 > this.variable2) {
    var x = 1/2 * (this.variable2 / this.variable1);
  } else  { 
    var x = 1- 1 / 2 * this.variable1 / this.variable2; 
  }
   return x.toFixed(2); 
});
```

For a while this code has been working. Yet it is unreliable for some reason. The if clause `if (this.variable1 > this.variable2)` seems to sometimes evaluate as true even when it isn't, and thereby the wrong portion of code is run. In case it is relevant, Variable 1 and Variable 2 are also virtuals, calculated in preceding sections of code. They are integers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm delighted to be able to answer my own question! For some reason, the other virtuals I was using in this script, despite being numbers, were not numbers according to Javascript. To carry out accurate numerical functions, therefore, I had to convert them. I did this using the `Number()` function. Once this was done then everything worked as expected.